# Regex match for hh:mm:ss

Tags: regex

I am trying to match hh:mm:ss , but hh part is optional and I only want digits for capturing groups.

For example, my data is

- 1:04:12
- 43:32
- 12:11

Regex output should be [1,04,12], [43,43] and [12,11]

Comment: Isn't it easier to `explode(':', $input);` then check the number of returned pieces and validate them individually? `regex` is not quite the right tool to check if a value belongs to a provided range of values.

Comment: You have specified the requirements and the expected output. So, what's the problem/question that has come up in your own solution?

Comment: Which language are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:(\d{1,2}):)?(\d{2}):(\d{2})
```

http://rubular.com/r/aWlTwgJKVn

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/y3nDJM2uPsxhprye)

To disallow minutes and seconds >=60 change to this regexp

```
(?:(\d{1,2}):?)([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)
```

a little bit simpler would be this regexp but this also matches a time like `412:35` with a missing `:`

```
 (\d{0,2}):?(\d{2}):(\d{2})
```

Comment: This is what I come up with as well, but in your rubular link, match 2 returns a nil value for the first part. Isn't the point of non-capturing part not to get that group?

Comment: getting the nil value makes your result more consistent as you have optional `hh` in group1 and `mm` is always group2, `ss` is  always group3. Otherwise the result would be pretty nasty to interprete...